# Confusion related to convexity of 0-1 loss function

Tags: convex-optimization

I am a bit confused why the 0-1 loss function is not convex. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Could you provide a little more background? I've taken classes in nonlinear optimization, and I have no idea what a 0-1 loss function is.

Comment: Perhaps you're referring to {0,1}-valued *indicator* functions? If so, Geoff's answer below still applies.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but here goes:

A zero-one loss function $L: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ is defined as:

\begin{align}
L(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0, & \textrm{if $x \geq 0$}, \\ 1, & \textrm{if $x < 0.$}\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

$L$ is convex if, for all $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, and all $\lambda \in [0,1]$,

\begin{align}
L(\lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda)x_2) \leq \lambda L(x_1) + (1 - \lambda) L(x_2).
\end{align}

A counterexample is: $(x_1, x_2, \lambda) = (-1, 1/2, 1/2)$.

Then:

\begin{align}
L(\lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda)x_2) &= L(-1/4) = 1, \\
L(x_1) &= 1, \\
L(x_2) &= 0,
\end{align}

and $L(\lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda)x_2) \leq \lambda L(x_1) + (1 - \lambda) L(x_2)$ does not hold, because $1 \leq 1/2$ is not true, so $L$ is not convex.